# One router seemingly cancels other router on a multiple router network setup

Tags: networking, router, lan

There is a main router (Router 0 (TP-Link WR850N)) and two routers (Router 1, Router 2 (Netis WF2409E)) are connected with it as LAN (LAN of Router 0 to WAN of Router 1 and Router 2). Both have DHCP servers enabled.

But there is only one visible network most of the times, either Router 1 or Router 2.

Sometimes and for some phone it's Router 2, for some it's Router 1. Also If a phone is connected with one of the networks of Router 1 or Router 2, other wifi network doesn't even show up.

I've checked with different phones but same thing happens with all of them.

When I turn off DHCP server of one router then both shows up but I can connect to only one router.

How can I fix that? What settings do I have to change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your intention to have two intranet subnets?  Why are you expecting to be able to connect to the 2nd router while connected to the first router?

Comment: I meant only one network is visible, other one is not. And also it's not same for all the phones, it seemed arbitrary to me. Sometimes only R#1 is visible and sometimes R#2. So, user can't find his desired network

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, i don't understand intranet subnet. Can you please explain?

Comment: Look up what an intranet IP address is and you will better understand my question

Comment: @Ramhound I got that now. Yes I want that. If I ask it very easily, from one internet connection and one parent router how do you make it three private wifi network (best way)?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the 2nd router. Most people would use the 2nd router to extend the range of their network.  You have effectively created two separate networks by having two routers with DHCP enabled on them.

Comment: I want three usable distinct wifi networks that's why 2nd router is used. Isn't it okay?

Comment: @Fuad Please [edit] your question to add the makes and models of the routers - some of them allow for more than one WiFi network on one router.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Ok. Same question to you, from one internet connection and one parent router how would you make three private wifi networks?

Comment: @Fuad I notice that the [features list](https://www.netis-systems.com/Home/detail/id/42.html) for the Netis router includes "Multi-SSID providing up to 3 additional separate networks for guests and friends." The configuration instructions may take some finding, or they might be available via the config interface of the router.

Answer (score -2):

1. Check and take note of the IP address of the main router.  For detailed instructions on how to do this, [click here](https://kb.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=132891).
2. Connect your computer to one of the ethernet ports of the secondary router.
3. Access the web-based setup page of the secondary router.  For instructions, [click here](https://kb.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=135561).  If you’re using a Mac® computer, [click here](https://kb.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=143269).
4. Under the **Basic Setup** sub-tab, look for **IP Address** or **Local IP Address**.

**NOTE**:  If the IP address is the same as the main router, change the fourth octet (the number in the fourth box) to a different value.

**Example**: Main router:  192.168.1.1 -> Secondary router should be:  192.168.1.2

5. For the **DHCP Server Setting**, set the **DHCP Server** to **Disabled**.
6. Click **Save Settings**.
7. Unplug the cable from your computer and connect it to one of the **Ethernet** ports on the main router.  Make sure the main router is still connected to the modem via its **Internet** port.
8. Powercycle the secondary router and once the **Power** light is solid, check whether you're able to access the internet on your devices.

**NOTE:**  A single router that is set in Bridge mode will disable the Guest Access feature of the router.  In cascading routers, specifically **LAN to LAN** connections, setting the secondary router to Bridge mode would not allow access for guests.  However, Guest Access is still permissible if the connections are **LAN to WAN.**

Comment: Thanks. That's detailed. Some questions, 1. Should it be LAN to WAN or LAN to LAN? 2. What are the ethernet ports on routers? I only can see WAN amd LAN port?

Comment: @JunaidRehman - If you are going to copy and paste text from an external website it must be properly cited and quoted.  Improperly cited third-party reference material, in this case unquoted reference material, will be treated as plagiarism.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: -1 [This post](https://www.linksys.com/za/support-article?articleNum=132275) is copied and pasted directly from this Linksys support page without modification or even anything that addresses the the core question directly.

Comment: my purpose is to provide detail regarding issue, links attached to my post redirect to the page from where that information placed.

Comment: @JunaidRehman - Feel free to do that by authoring your own content, or properly citing and quoting third-party material.  Your original answer was unformatted and was literally just copied and pasted, which made it unacceptable.  I personally wouldn't have spend time editing your answer but that's just me.

Comment: @JunaidRehman “…links attached to my post redirect to the page from where that information placed.” No they don’t. They are links that exist in the LinkSys content to begin with and utterly _none_ of them link to the article you swiped this from. Again, copying content from other sources is acceptable as long as it is clear it is copied content and the context is clearly set. I did a friendly edit to simply get this in proper list format. Even with proper list format this answer is not an answer.